# Using a function to dynamically generate tags

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to display dynamic tags. I cannot seem to get the line-breaks for my css to look good. The container is responsive and it therefore has to break nicely:

CSS:

```
.tags {
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    padding-top: 0.25em;
    padding-bottom: 0.25em;
    margin: 0.5em;
}
```

displaying it like so:

```
mapTags = tagArray => {
  return tagArray.map((item, i) => <span key={i} className={styles.tags}>
  {item}</span>);
};
```

Help please.

Bonus: sometimes the tags contain spaces like e.g. "This is a tag". How to solve the breaking of my borders here?

Comment: Can you provide a working fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<span>` is an inline element. Try using `<div>`.
If somehow it is necessary to use span, try applying `display: block` property. But that is not the ideal way to do it, even if it works.